# Kotlin: how to return some value from scope?

Tags: kotlin

In Scala I can write something like this:

```
val something = {
  val temp1 = ...
  val temp2 = ...
  temp1 + temp2
}
```

As far as I know the best way to do the same in Kotlin is:

```
val something = {
  val temp1 = ...
  val temp2 = ...
  temp1 + temp2
}()
```

Actually it's a lambda with type Unit -> Int which is called immediately. I wonder could this code be improved somehow? Maybe there is a built in function which allows me to write val something = block { ... } or something like this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use function `run`, like:

```
val something = run {
  val temp1 = ...
  val temp2 = ...
  temp1 + temp2
}
```

Comment: That's the same thing (even more verbose) than what the OP posted?

Comment: Now you edited it, it's exactly what he's looking for.